# Validating brackets attempt has performance issue

Tags: javascript, performance

I have spent many hours trying to solve the Valid Parentheses problem on Leetcode at https://leetcode.com/problems/valid-parentheses/

Although my solution correctly identifies a number of strings as valid or invalid in terms of the arrangement of {, }, (, ), [ and ] characters in the string, it fails on Leetcode with a
runtime error message.

I have included my code in a snippet

```js
var isValid = function(s){
    // In the comments the word brackets applies to any of...
    // ...the elements in the pairs array eg. ( and } and [ etc.
    // op means opening bracket ie. (, { or [
    // cl means closing bracket ie. ), } or ]
    console.log('***********');
    console.log(s);
    // In the script the first element of testArrays is removed...
    // ...and supplied to checkArrays() as an argument.
    // checkArrays() returns false if the first level of brackets...
    // ...is invalid.
    // If it does not return false, checkArrays() returns an array...
    // ...of arrays each containing the contents of the first level...
    // ...of brackets. These are pushed to testArrays.
    // When there are no arrays left in testArrays the script returns true.
    let testArrays = [[...s]];
    const pairs = [['(',')'], ['[',']'], ['{', '}']];

    function containsBrackets(array){
        for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < pairs.length; j++){
                if(array[i] === pairs[j][0]){
                    return true;
                }
                if(array[i] === pairs[j][1]){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function checkArray(array){
        const resultArray = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++){
            let op = pairs[i][0];
            let cl = pairs[i][1];
            let opIdx = [];
            let clIdx = [];
            for(let j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
                if(array[j] === cl){
                    // record index of cl
                    clIdx.push(j)
                    if(clIdx.length > opIdx.length){
                        // There was a cl before matching op
                        return false;
                    }
                    if(clIdx.length === opIdx.length){
                        // 1 or more op matched by same number of cl
                        // Therefore add substring between the outer...
                        // ...brackets to resultArray
                        resultArray.push(
                            array.slice(opIdx[0] + 1, clIdx[clIdx.length - 1])
                        );
                        opIdx = [];
                        clIdx = [];
                    }
                }
                if(array[j] === op){
                    // record index of op
                    opIdx.push(j);
                }
            }
            if(opIdx.length > 0){
                // There was an op without matching cl
                return false;
            }
        }
        for(let i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++){
            // Only keep arrays which contain 1 or more brackets
            // Ie. remove arrays which contain no brackets
            if(!containsBrackets(resultArray[i])){
                resultArray.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        return resultArray;
    }

    let newArrays = [];
    let tempArr = [];
    while(testArrays.length > 0){
        tempArr = testArrays.shift();
        newArrays = checkArray(tempArr);
        if(newArrays){
            for(let i = 0; i < newArrays.length; i++){
                testArrays.push(newArrays[i]);
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
    // checkArray() never returned false and...
    // ...testArrays.length was reduce to 0.
    return true;

}

values = [ "(())", "()()", "()(7)x", "()(", "]", "[", "[[]", "[]", "[][]", "[][", "()[]{}", "()[{}", "(){}}{", "(})", "({)}", "abcde!" ];
values.forEach(value => {
    console.log(isValid(value));
});
```

The runtime error message when I submit it on Leetcode is:

```
    <--- Last few GCs --->
[30:0x6141180]      962 ms: Scavenge 111.1 (144.1) -> 111.0 (144.1) MB, 8.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.894, current mu = 0.894) allocation failure
[30:0x6141180]      969 ms: Scavenge 111.1 (144.1) -> 111.0 (144.1) MB, 6.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.894, current mu = 0.894) allocation failure
[30:0x6141180]      973 ms: Scavenge 111.1 (144.1) -> 111.0 (144.1) MB, 4.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.894, current mu = 0.894) allocation failure
<--- JS stacktrace --->
FATAL ERROR: Scavenger: semi-space copy Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb00e10 node::Abort() [nodejs run]
 2: 0xa1823b node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [nodejs run]
 3: 0xcee09e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [nodejs run]
 4: 0xcee417 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [nodejs run]
 5: 0xea65d5  [nodejs run]
 6: 0xf1fc4e v8::internal::SlotCallbackResult v8::internal::Scavenger::ScavengeObject<v8::internal::FullHeapObjectSlot>(v8::internal::FullHeapObjectSlot, v8::internal::HeapObject) [nodejs run]
 7: 0xf200f5  [nodejs run]
 8: 0xf21e22 void v8::internal::BodyDescriptorApply<v8::internal::CallIterateBody, void, v8::internal::Map, v8::internal::HeapObject, int, v8::internal::IterateAndScavengePromotedObjectsVisitor*>(v8::internal::InstanceType, v8::internal::Map, v8::internal::HeapObject, int, v8::internal::IterateAndScavengePromotedObjectsVisitor*) [nodejs run]
 9: 0xf22d52 v8::internal::Scavenger::IterateAndScavengePromotedObject(v8::internal::HeapObject, v8::internal::Map, int) [nodejs run]
10: 0xf240c3 v8::internal::Scavenger::Process(v8::JobDelegate*) [nodejs run]
11: 0xf2471f v8::internal::ScavengerCollector::JobTask::ProcessItems(v8::JobDelegate*, v8::internal::Scavenger*) [nodejs run]
12: 0xf24860 v8::internal::ScavengerCollector::JobTask::Run(v8::JobDelegate*) [nodejs run]
13: 0x18e5876 v8::platform::DefaultJobState::Join() [nodejs run]
14: 0x18e58e3 v8::platform::DefaultJobHandle::Join() [nodejs run]
15: 0xf259f3 v8::internal::ScavengerCollector::CollectGarbage() [nodejs run]
16: 0xea6c25 v8::internal::Heap::Scavenge() [nodejs run]
17: 0xeb5050  [nodejs run]
18: 0xeb5a30 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [nodejs run]
19: 0xeb89ae v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [nodejs run]
20: 0xe79dda v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [nodejs run]
21: 0x11f33d6 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [nodejs run]
22: 0x15e7cf9  [nodejs run]
```

Leetcode also says that the Last executed input was `"[([([([([....` I have left off about 17000 characters from that.

Given that it seems to be failing when the input string is very large, and there is mention of "heap out of memory" I think my script must be inefficient in some way.

I would like help understanding what the message means and why my code is failing and how to improve it.

Comment: I can't follow this code, but it's far more complicated than it needs to be. Just use a simple stack. When you get an open bracket, you push it onto the stack. When you get a close bracket you pop the stack, and check that it matches the current bracket.

Comment: if you need to save memory, you can optimize the stack for consecutive repeats of the same character, by holding a counter. Although that example will confound this because it simply alternates brackets. I'm not sure if there are better optimizations.

Comment: @Barmar When you say stack do you mean an array?

Comment: An array is the data structure you would most likely use to implement a stack.

Comment: @Barmar really appreciate your help! I got it to work with far less code and it ran fast and with low memory usage. I read up about stacks...

Comment: You could post your rewrite as an answer. You're allowed to answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I received for my question I have implemented a much simpler approach. This script pushes opening brakcets onto a stack and then pops them off when a closing, matching bracket is encountered. If the opening and closing brackets do not match it returns false.

This ran much faster and with much lower memory usage than the script in my question and passed the Leetcode submission testing.

```js
var isValid = function(s){
    console.log('s:', s);
    const arr = [...s];
    const stack = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(
            arr[i] === '(' ||
            arr[i] === '{' ||
            arr[i] === '['
        ){
            // add opening brackets to stack
            stack.push(arr[i]);
        }
        // When closing brackets are encountered...
        // ...test last added opening bracket on stack...
        // If they match continue otherwise return false.
        if(arr[i] === ')'){
            if(stack[stack.length-1] === '('){
                stack.pop();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(arr[i] === '}'){
            if(stack[stack.length-1] === '{'){
                stack.pop();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if(arr[i] === ']'){
            if(stack[stack.length-1] === '['){
                stack.pop();
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // An opening bracket had no matching closing bracket
    if(stack.length > 0){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

values = ["(())", "()()", "()(7)x", "()(", "]", "[", "[[]", "[]", "(){}}{", "(})", "({)}", "abcde!"];
values.forEach(value => {
    console.log(isValid(value));
    console.log('*******************************');
});
```